# Expected number of bottles to get a prize

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

I want to solve the following problem: the limonade company claims that $37\%$ of bottles contain prizes under the cap. What is the Expected number of bottles I need to buy to get a prize?

Am I right that this is a geometric distribution? So should the expected value be $p\left(1-p\right)$?

Comment: Expected number of bottles = $1/0.37=2.703$

Comment: @user295357 so it is geometric distribution (I later noticed, I wrote the expected value formula wrong)?

Comment: @themathfan Yes, the geometric distribution is the right one.